# android imageview into Relative layout set height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I have an image view into `Relativelayout`, I pick the image from the gallery .. the problem is the `Imageview` height is too big and the relative layout parent height become the same as the `Imageview` height, I need to pick image from gallery and display it into this relative layout exactly.

below my code

```
    <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/crayon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What do you want exactly ?

Comment: try using `android:scaleType="fitXY"` ..

Comment: i want to let imageview height fit the relative layout height exactly,, not bigger

Comment: set height to relative layout

Comment: You are using adjustViewBounds on the ImageView while it's parent RelativeLayout has wrap_content. 
Either take care of the aspect ration by yourself:     android:adjustViewBounds="false"
or limit the height of the relative layout.

Comment: no solution works?..

Comment: i give the relative layout a fixed height 200 dp so it works

Answer (score 1):

try this: remove `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"`

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/calender" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/bgg"
    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="71dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting same problem: try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/guide3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```